# XCode Auto delete plist on debug

Tags: xcode, debugging, ios, cocos2d-iphone, plist

My program relies mainly on plist files. But every time i edit something in a plist file i have to remove the application from the device and reinstall it. Is there an easier way to do this? Like is it possible all the plist files get deleted automatically when i build/debug

Answer (score 0):

... I rely alot on plist too but i just save the plist and build and its done..

You can try Build -> clean all targets and build again...